# How do I update a dataset column quickly in Aviarc

Tags: aviarc

For example, I've got a button that iterates though a dataset and sets one field to a value.

```xml
<button left="10" width="100" bottom="12" height="32" label="Select All" enabled-if-dataset="data">
    <when event="onClick" xmlns="urn:aviarc:widget:com.aviarc.toronto.widget.core.action:1">
        <dataset:dataset-iterator dataset="data">
            <set-field field="data.selected" value="y"/>
        </dataset:dataset-iterator>
    </when>
</button>
```

This works fine on smaller datasets, but now I've got a dataset with 400 rows in it, and it has a noticeable delay when run.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would recommend doing that would be by the following algorithm:

- disable relevant events on the dataset bound to the record table
- do the iteration with fields update
- re-enable the dataset events
- trigger the event which will refresh the record table

I would wrap the update into the Javascript action widget. The extraction below is from Aviarc 3.6 where I was doing similar thing (from the run method), but you should be able to adjust it for your needs:

```
/* disable all events on the target dataset which would most likely trigger some widget behaviours */
var dsEvents = [
    "ONDATASETCHANGED"
    ,"ONDATACHANGED"
    ,"ONLOCALDATACHANGED"
    ,"ONCONTENTSREPLACED"
    ,"ONCURRENTROWCHANGED"
    ,"ONROWCREATED"
    ,"ONROWDELETED"
    ,"ONROWADDED"
    ,"ONCURRENTROWDELETED"
    ,"ONROWCOMMITACTIONCHANGED"
    ,"ONCURRENTROWCOMMITACTIONCHANGED"
    ,"ONROWFIELDCHANGED"
    ,"ONCURRENTROWFIELDCHANGED"
];
var events = toDS.getEvents();
for (var i = 0, count = dsEvents.length; i < count; i++) { 
    events.getEventByName(dsEvents[i]).disable(); 
}
toDS.deleteAllRows();
fromDS.getAllRows().doLoop(function(fromDSRow) {
    if (doFiltering) {
        if (fromDSRow.getField(userIDField) == userID) {
            this._copyRow(fromDSRow, toDS.createRow());
        }
    } else {
        this._copyRow(fromDSRow, toDS.createRow());
    }
}, this);
toDS.reset();
/* enable all events back */
for (var i = 0, count = dsEvents.length; i < count; i++) { 
    events.getEventByName(dsEvents[i]).enable(); 
}
/* trigger refresh on the widgets as if we just updated ds via ajax */
toDS.onContentsReplaced.fireEvent();
toDS.onDataChanged.fireEvent();
toDS.onDatasetChanged.fireEvent();
```

Comment: Noting that individual dataset rows have their own events as well, onFieldChanged (which is different to dataset onRowFieldChanged) and onDataChanged at minimum, which will still be being fired in this setup. I'm concerned that this could lead to problems if there are any widgets which have handlers on row-level events and on dataset-level events and the handlers are expected to work in conjunction. I don't know if there are any widgets like that offhand, though.

Comment: @TristanWilkinson Reasonable note, although since I did not notice any widget which is bound to events on that level I avoid mentioning it here. But this is certainly a consideration to keep in mind.

One extra case to cater for could be data rules layer, since it is quite likely that some rule would be listening to the row-level events.